# PC bluescreened, shut off. No monitor signal, and case was tingling

Tags: windows, bsod

I have a eMachine with windows 7 home premium. I just got done doing a video about my miniature tesla coil (I though that might be important, could induced static cause problems?) And i went to turn on my eMachine.

I was downloading a large file, when randomly the screen blacks, I get a blue screen, and then the pc reboots. After the reboot it froze on the bios splash screen. Any further reboots had  no monitor output.

When I had it off, when I went to unplug the pc to see what was wrong, I noticed the case tingling. I do not thing it is supposed to do that,  so I unplugged the entire power strip.

Is this a power supply problem? Was it caused by my tesla coil being near the pc? Or was it random?

Comment: Sounds like an electrical issue of some sort.  The MB is grounded to the case, so if the case is metal and it was energized in some fashion, this could cause MB damage.  It's highly unlikely this was caused by the power cord or power strip, as MBs run off of DC, but it is possible for the PC power supply to fault (very slim chance, but possible none the less).

Comment: i figured out the tingling case was because of a grounding issue in the extension cable i was using.

Comment: Extensions cords should not be used for PC power supplies... use a longer power cord that's the proper gauge for the amperage that will be utilized by the PC.  I personally always recommend [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/category/cables/power-cords?categoryPath3_uFilter=Extension%20Cords&categoryPath3_uFilter=Power%20Cords&menuDisStr=power%20cords&v_Connector_A_uFilter=NEMA%205-15P&v_Connector_A_uFilter=NEMA%205-20P&TotalProducts=13) cables, as they're inexpensive, high-quality cables and MonoPrice has a LifeTime Warranty on all their cables.